# Did Nikita Khrushchev make this remark about Switzerland?

Tags: quotes

It is alleged that Nikita Khrushchev said the [following](http://www.quoteland.com/author/Nikita-Khrushchev-Quotes/1962/):

> When all the world is socialist, Switzerland will have to remain capitalist, so that it can tell us the price of everything.

Did Nikita Khrushchev say the following? If not, I'm also interested in knowing who said this.

Comment: http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Talk:Nikita_Khrushchev lists it as unsourced.

Comment: @vartec maybe that link is also suggesting it's attributed to `"Intelligence Digest", Kenneth Hugh De Courcy, John De Courcy, 1976.`